# Custom Backend Module showing blank Page

Tags: adminhtml, layout, xml, exception

I am having a feeling this is a simple issue.  I have a module I created for Magento 1.7.0.2, however it's just showing a blank page when clicked.  Here are my module files:

```
app/code/community/LAMP/InkToner/Block/Adminhtml/InkTonerbackend.php
app/code/community/LAMP/InkToner/Helper/Data.php
app/code/community/LAMP/InkToner/controllers/Adminhtml/InktonerbackendController.php
app/code/community/LAMP/InkToner/etc/config.xml

app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/inktoner.xml
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/inktoner/inktonerbackend.phtml

app/etc/modules/LAMP_InkToner.xml
```

When checking logs, I find the exception as follows:

```
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: LAMP_InkToner_Block_Adminhtml_Inktonerbackend' in xxxxxx/app/Mage.php:594
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/DTS_LIVE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...')
#1 /var/www/DTS_LIVE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('inktoner/adminh...', Array)
#2 /var/www/DTS_LIVE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('inktoner/adminh...', 'inktonerbackend')
#3 /var/www/DTS_LIVE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('inktoner/adminh...', 'inktonerbackend')
#4 /var/www/DTS_LIVE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#5 /var/www/DTS_LIVE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#6 /var/www/DTS_LIVE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#7 /var/www/DTS_LIVE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#8 /var/www/DTS_LIVE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(275): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout(NULL, true, true)
#9 /var/www/DTS_LIVE/public_html/app/code/community/LAMP/InkToner/controllers/Adminhtml/InktonerbackendController.php(6): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->loadLayout()
#10 /var/www/DTS_LIVE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): LAMP_InkToner_Adminhtml_InktonerbackendController->indexAction()
#11 /var/www/DTS_LIVE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#12 /var/www/DTS_LIVE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#13 /var/www/DTS_LIVE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#14 /var/www/DTS_LIVE/public_html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#15 /var/www/DTS_LIVE/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#16 {main}
```

Since the module is pretty simple, I'll include the code for the various files.  I have tried the output for **mageFindClassFile('inktoner/adminhtml_inktonerbackend')** and didn't get a return ...

**InkTonerbackend.php**

```
<?php  
class LAMP_InkToner_Block_Adminhtml_InkTonerbackend extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template {
}
```

**Data.php**

```
<?php
class LAMP_InkToner_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract{}
```

**InktonerbackendController.php**

```
<?php
class LAMP_InkToner_Adminhtml_InktonerbackendController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
public function indexAction()
{
   $this->loadLayout();
   $this->_title($this->__("Ink And Toner Uploader"));
   $this->renderLayout();
}
}
```

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <LAMP_InkToner>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </LAMP_InkToner>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <inktoner>
        <class>LAMP_InkToner_Helper</class>
      </inktoner>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
      <inktoner>
        <class>LAMP_InkToner_Block</class>
      </inktoner>
    </blocks>
  </global>
  <admin>
    <routers>
      <inktoner>
        <use>admin</use>
        <args>
          <module>LAMP_InkToner</module>
          <frontName>inktoner</frontName>
        </args>
      </inktoner>
    </routers>
  </admin>
  <adminhtml>
    <menu>
      <inktoner module="inktoner">
        <title>InkToner</title>
        <sort_order>100</sort_order>
        <children>
          <inktonerbackend module="inktoner">
            <title>Ink And Toner Uploader</title>
            <sort_order>0</sort_order>
            <action>inktoner/adminhtml_inktonerbackend</action>
          </inktonerbackend>
        </children>
      </inktoner>
    </menu>
    <acl>
      <resources>
        <all>
          <title>Allow Everything</title>
        </all>
        <admin>
          <children>
            <inktoner translate="title" module="inktoner">
              <title>InkToner</title>
              <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
              <children>
          <inktonerbackend translate="title">
            <title>Ink And Toner Uploader</title>
          </inktonerbackend>
              </children>
            </inktoner>
          </children>
        </admin>
      </resources>
    </acl>
    <layout>
      <updates>
        <inktoner>
          <file>inktoner.xml</file>
        </inktoner>
      </updates>
    </layout>
  </adminhtml>
</config>
```

**inktoner.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
  <inktoner_adminhtml_inktonerbackend_index>
    <reference name="content">
      <block type="inktoner/adminhtml_inktonerbackend" name="inktonerbackend" template="inktoner/inktonerbackend.phtml"/>
    </reference>
  </inktoner_adminhtml_inktonerbackend_index>
</layout>
```

**inktonerbackend.phtml**

```
TEST TEST TEST
```

**LAMP_InkToner.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <LAMP_InkToner>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>community</codePool>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </LAMP_InkToner>
  </modules>
</config>
```

Can anyone see anything obvious that would cause that exception??  Any assistance appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the exception call stack

```
#0 /var/www/DTS_LIVE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...')
#1 /var/www/DTS_LIVE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('inktoner/adminh...', Array)
```

The method `_getBlockInstance` is throwing the "Invalid Block Type" exception.  That information in hand, look at the `_getBlockInstance` method definition.

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php
482    protected function _getBlockInstance($block, array $attributes=array())
483    {
484        if (is_string($block)) {
485            if (strpos($block, '/')!==false) {
486                if (!$block = Mage::getConfig()->getBlockClassName($block)) {
487                    Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('core')->__('Invalid block type: %s', $block));
488                }
489            }
490            if (class_exists($block, false) || mageFindClassFile($block)) {
491                $block = new $block($attributes);
492            }
493        }
494        if (!$block instanceof Mage_Core_Block_Abstract) {
495            Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('core')->__('Invalid block type: %s', $block));
496        }
497        return $block;
498    }
```

Referring again to our call stack, we see that `Mage::throwException` was called at line `495`

```
#0 ... /Layout.php(495)
```

Looking at the `if` clause that surrounds line 495

```
if (!$block instanceof Mage_Core_Block_Abstract) {
    Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('core')->__('Invalid block type: %s', $block));
}
```

This means one of three things is wrong

1. Your `inktoner/adminhtml_inktonerbackend` class alias doesn't properly return a class name when passed to `mageFindClassFile('inktoner/adminhtml_inktonerbackend')`
2. The class name it resolves to doesn't match the class name in `app/code/community/LAMP/InkToner/Block/Adminhtml/InkTonerbackend.php`
3. The block class from #2 doesn't include `Mage_Core_Block_Abstract` in its ancestry chain

Comment: Thank you for the info!  Is there a way to determine what the class name is that is returned (if returned) from `mageFindClassFile('inktoner/adminhtml_inktonerbackend')`?  If not returned I can delve into that.  If reutrned, I can compare to `InktonerbackendController.php`.

Comment: @Zak 1. Just call the function from someplace in Magento and look at the return value.  2. I copy pasted the wrong class from above, it's `app/code/community/LAMP/InkToner/Block/Adminhtml/InkTonerbackend.php` you're interested in, not `InktonerbackendController.php`